# How to make it into BCNF

Tags: sql, database, schema, normalization, bcnf

Good morning,
I wonder how I can make sure this schema is in BCNF.

petition(ID, title, contents, budget, organizationID, official, resultID, applicantID)

applicant(ID, name)

official(ID, name, department)

organization(ID, name, phoneNumber)

*Each petition has an official.

*Each petition should have more than one organization.

> This is the hardest option that I cannot handle. With the same petitionID, there can be several organizations. Also, even though I insert several tuples whose elements are the same except organizationID, if there is any change in budget or result, those tuples should be changed together without causing any anomaly.

*budget can be NULL.

*The result would be filled after they deal with the problem.

Comment: What are all the FDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you write, I understand there's a many-to-many relationship between "petition" and "organization".
This means you need an additional table representing this relationship.
E.g.:

petition(ID, title, contents, budget, official, resultID, applicantID)

applicant(ID, name)

official(ID, name, department)

organization(ID, name, phoneNumber)

and

organization_petition(organizationID, petitionID)